# HTML form only submits free of errors if every field is completed

Tags: php, html

The form below works regardless of whether or not all of the fields are filled out.  This is what I want.  However, if I leave some fields blank, I get some "Filename cannot be empty" errors.  How can I eliminate those error messages?

```
echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://www...com/.../submit2a.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$_SESSION['loginid'].'" name="uid">  

    <div class="submissiontitle"><label for="title">Blog Post Title:</label></div> 
    <div class="submissionfield"><input class="checkMax3" name="title" type="title" id="title" maxlength="80"></div>  

    <div class="texttitle"><label for="text1">Blog Post Text 1:</label></div> 
    <div class="textfield"><textarea class="checkMax" name="text1" type="comment" id="text1" maxlength="10000"></textarea></div>

    <div class="imagetitle"><label for="image1">Image 1:</label></div> 
    <div class="imagefield"><input type="file" name="image1" /></div>   

    <div class="hyperlinktitle"><label for="url1">Hyperlink 1:</label></div> 
    <div class="hyperlinkfield "><input name="url1" type="title" id="url1" maxlength="200"></div>

    <div class="texttitle2"><label for="text2">Blog Post Text 2:</label></div> 
    <div class="textfield2"><textarea class="checkMax" name="text2" type="comment" id="text2" maxlength="10000"></textarea></div>

    <div class="imagetitle2"><label for="image2">Image 2:</label></div> 
    <div class="imagefield2"><input type="file" name="image2" /></div>  

    <div class="hyperlinktitle2"><label for="url2">Hyperlink 2:</label></div> 
    <div class="hyperlinkfield2"><input name="url2" type="text" id="url2" maxlength="200"></div>

    <div class="texttitle3"><label for="text3">Blog Post Text 3:</label></div> 
    <div class="textfield3"><textarea class="checkMax" name="text3" type="comment" id="text3" maxlength="10000"></textarea></div>

    <div class="imagetitle3"><label for="image3">Image 3:</label></div> 
    <div class="imagefield3"><input type="file" name="image3" /></div>  

    <div class="hyperlinktitle3"><label for="url3">Hyperlink 3:</label></div> 
    <div class="hyperlinkfield3"><input name="url3" type="text" id="url3" maxlength="200"></div>

    <div class="texttitle4"><label for="text4">Blog Post Text 4:</label></div> 
    <div class="textfield4"><textarea class="checkMax" name="text4" type="comment" id="text4" maxlength="10000"></textarea></div>

    <div class="imagetitle4"><label for="image4">Image 4:</label></div> 
    <div class="imagefield4"><input type="file" name="image4" /></div>  

    <div class="hyperlinktitle4"><label for="url4">Hyperlink 4:</label></div> 
    <div class="hyperlinkfield4"><input name="url4" type="text" id="url4" maxlength="200"></div>

    <div class="submissionbutton"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div> 
</form>
';
```

EDIT: In case it might help, here is most of submit2a.php:

```
$remove_array = array('http://www.', 'http://', 'https://', 'https://www.', 'www.');

$uid = $_POST['uid'];

$title = $_POST['title'];

$text1 = $_POST['text1'];

$image1 = $_POST['image1'];

$image1 = $_FILES['image1'];

$url1 = $_POST['url1'];



$text2 = $_POST['text2'];

$image2 = $_POST['image2'];

$image2 = $_FILES['image2'];

$url2 = $_POST['url2'];



$text3 = $_POST['text3'];

$image3 = $_POST['image3'];

$image3 = $_FILES['image3'];

$url3 = $_POST['url3'];



$text4 = $_POST['text4'];

$image4 = $_POST['image4'];

$image4 = $_FILES['image4'];

$url4 = $_POST['url4'];







$cleanurl1 = str_replace($remove_array, "", $_POST['url1']);
$cleanurl1 = strtolower($cleanurl1);
$cleanurl1 = preg_replace('/\/$/','',$cleanurl1);
$cleanurl1 = stripslashes($cleanurl1);
$cleanurl1 = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($cleanurl1));

$cleanurl2 = str_replace($remove_array, "", $_POST['url2']);
$cleanurl2 = strtolower($cleanurl2);
$cleanurl2 = preg_replace('/\/$/','',$cleanurl2);
$cleanurl2 = stripslashes($cleanurl2);
$cleanurl2 = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($cleanurl2));


$cleanurl3 = str_replace($remove_array, "", $_POST['url3']);
$cleanurl3 = strtolower($cleanurl3);
$cleanurl3 = preg_replace('/\/$/','',$cleanurl3);
$cleanurl3 = stripslashes($cleanurl3);
$cleanurl3 = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($cleanurl3));

$cleanurl4 = str_replace($remove_array, "", $_POST['url4']);
$cleanurl4 = strtolower($cleanurl4);
$cleanurl4 = preg_replace('/\/$/','',$cleanurl4);
$cleanurl4 = stripslashes($cleanurl4);
$cleanurl4 = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($cleanurl4));



//$url = $_POST['url'];

//$subcheck = (isset($_POST['subcheck'])) ? 1 : 0;
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$title = stripslashes($title);
$slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $title);




echo '-'.$site1.'-';



$site1 = 'http://' . $cleanurl1;
$site2 = 'http://' . $cleanurl2;
$site3 = 'http://' . $cleanurl3;
$site4 = 'http://' . $cleanurl4;

$displayurl = parse_url($site1, PHP_URL_HOST);




    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO submission VALUES (NULL, '$title', '$text1', '$text2', '$text3', '$text4', '$site1', '$site2', '$site3', '$site4', NULL)");


mysql_query($query);

        $id = (int) mysql_insert_id($db);   

$submissionid = $id;        



$info1 = getImageSize($image1['tmp_name']);

$queryimage1 = sprintf(
            "insert into images (NULL, submissionid, filename, mime_type, file_size, file_data)
                values ('%s', '%s', '%s', %d, '%s')",
            $submissionid,
            mysql_real_escape_string($image1['name']),
            mysql_real_escape_string($info1['mime']),
            $image1['size'],
            mysql_real_escape_string(
                file_get_contents($image1['tmp_name'])
            )
        )or die(mysql_error());





$info2 = getImageSize($image2['tmp_name']);

$queryimage2 = sprintf(
            "insert into images (NULL, ubmissionid, filename, mime_type, file_size, file_data)
                values ('%s', '%s', '%s', %d, '%s')",
            $submissionid,
            mysql_real_escape_string($image2['name']),
            mysql_real_escape_string($info2['mime']),
            $image2['size'],
            mysql_real_escape_string(
                file_get_contents($image2['tmp_name'])
            )
        )or die(mysql_error());     




 $info3 = getImageSize($image3['tmp_name']);

$queryimage3 = sprintf(
            "insert into images (NULL, submissionid, filename, mime_type, file_size, file_data)
                values ('%s', '%s', '%s', %d, '%s')",
            $submissionid,
            mysql_real_escape_string($image3['name']),
            mysql_real_escape_string($info3['mime']),
            $image3['size'],
            mysql_real_escape_string(
                file_get_contents($image3['tmp_name'])
            )
        )or die(mysql_error());



 $info4 = getImageSize($image4['tmp_name']);

$queryimage4 = sprintf(
            "insert into images (NULL, submissionid, filename, mime_type, file_size, file_data)
                values ('%s', '%s', '%s', %d, '%s')",
            $submissionid,
            mysql_real_escape_string($image4['name']),
            mysql_real_escape_string($info4['mime']),
            $image4['size'],
            mysql_real_escape_string(
                file_get_contents($image4['tmp_name'])
            )
        )or die(mysql_error());     


//mysql_free_result($result);







header("Location: http://www...com/.../");
exit();
```

Comment: I have a feeling the error you're getting... is not derived from this piece of code alone. Post more code!

Comment: What is giving you those error messages?  Those messages don't come from this, they come from whatever is processing the form.  We need to see that source before we can help you.

Comment: The problem might be in the PHP part of the code. Post your PHP code.

Comment: as a side note inputs directly in a from is not valid html also you should close the inputs <input type="text />

Comment: Yeesh. Break of out PHP mode with a `?>` and just emit html directly. There's absolutely ZERO need to do it via an echo.

Comment: Not only ZERO need it is absolute overkill if you try to refactor the code afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely to be a problem with your database - if fields can be added even when empty, then make sure all the relevant fields in the database are set to allow NULL values.

The error you're getting back is a database error - the field isn't set to accept a null value (empty field from the form).